# Next, previous buttons not shown in md-paginator [Angular 4]

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

As shown in the picture below, am not seeing the icons [< >] as part of Next, Previous buttons.

I have below modules imported

```
MdPaginatorModule,
MdSelectModule
```

[image: Next, previous buttons don't have icons]

I tried to import MdIconModule but it didn't make a difference

Comment: plz ignore, I just had to import <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">